# callback function in .each() method for Async package in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

In the document of Async package, `each()` method takes 3 argument `each(coll, iteratee, callback)`. My question is not about the 3rd argument `callback`, but the another "callback" function in the 2nd argument `iteratee`.

It says `iteratee` is a type of `AsyncFunction()` function, which also takes a `callback` function as the argument. Here is the example provided in the document.

```
// assuming openFiles is an array of file names
async.each(openFiles, function(file, callback) {

  // Perform operation on file here.
  console.log('Processing file ' + file);

  if( file.length > 32 ) {
    console.log('This file name is too long');
    callback('File name too long');
  } else {
    // Do work to process file here
    console.log('File processed');
    callback();
  }
}, function(err) {
  // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
  if( err ) {
    // One of the iterations produced an error.
    // All processing will now stop.
    console.log('A file failed to process');
  } else {
    console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
  }
});
```

In this example, the second argument `function(file, callback)` should be the `iteratee` function. However, I do not understand where and what its `callback` argument is defined. It has been called in the above example with `callback('File name too long');` and `callback('File name too long');` but what exactly this function does? By intuition, this function might be called when the `file` is done processing to notify this fact. But where I could find the exact code of this `callback` function?

Comment: You would find the code inside the implementation of `each`, which passes the function to the iteratee. But don't go looking for it - it's pretty convoluted code. Yes, the `callback` is supposed to be called when the iteratee has finished, with either a result or an error, and calling it will trigger the next step in whatever `async.each` does.

Comment: That example is horrible because there actually is nothing asynchronous happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can find the callback defined [here](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/eachOf.js) via the `iteratorCallback` function.

Comment: It seems that it has something to do with the 3rd argument `callback` (like a kind of wrap function of it). I did not dive into the `onlyOnce()` function, but is it reasonable to assume that if there is any error happening during the execution of `iteratee`, the `callback` would be called with `error` argument. Otherwise, when all the processes done the job, the `callback` function would be eventually called with `null` argument?

Comment: Yes exactly. In the example you posted the `callback` called by `iteratee` refers to the last argument supplied to async.each - `function(err)`